# How to enable Development mode in Developer account

Tags: developer, console, sublime

I tried to work with Visual force page. One page opend but there is no develope mode. How to enable Developer mode in Developer Edition

Answer (score 2):

Go to your user profile--> edit -->enable development mode ( show view state also gets checked automatically)

[image]